# Preserve metadata when uploading multiple files to an Amazon S3 bucket using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an archive of files for a client that needs uploading to an s3 bucket (100,000+ files). From there, the files need to be listed & available for download on their website.

It is crucial that the files I upload preserve the 'Date Created' or 'Date Modified' metadata in order for the files to be listed in the original date they were created. [User-defined metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata) is also fine, as long as I can get the data after upload.

I've tried using the following command on AWS CLI as a test:

```
aws s3 cp test.pdf s3://test-bucket/ --metadata-directive COPY
```

however it doesn't preserve the original metadata. Is there a bug with the COPY command or am I missing something? Any advice or alternative ways I could achieve this would be appreciated, thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

`--metadata-directive` take effect only if source and destination path are both s3 path, has no effect to local files. Here you could pass local file attributes as `--metadata` (User-defined metadata) for new created s3 object. for example:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
file="$1"
meta=$(stat --printf='{"x-change-time":"%z","x-access-time":"%x","x-modify-time":"%y"}' $file)
aws s3 cp "$file" s3://test-bucket/ --metadata "$meta"
```

```
test.sh ./test.pdf
```

Comment: Looks good! I am very excited to try out your code.. Although wouldn't this method require me to create a variable ($file) for every single file?

Comment: i have updated the script, now you can pass the file path as argument